# How to passively generate leads (writing)?

Tags: writing, advertising

I've created my website to sell services. Now what? There's no way I compete for keywords on platforms like Google Ads, as that's way too expensive. I believe the website has been indexed on both Google and Bing. I've also posted that website on social media such as LinkedIn, although I don't think I'm fully taking advantage of those platforms. Instead of waiting for a client to magically contact me through the site, what should I do?

Comment: Must the (first) clients be generated passively? Typically, getting clients in the beginning is way more difficult, meaning all approaches should be considered. After having built a reputation, attracting clients may require less effort and perhaps even be done passively

Comment: I know, and so far my clients are from me actively bidding on job posts. I am somewhat established with a few published works, which is why I created the website to begin with. Many writers I know get high-paying clients just by sitting there because they have a website!

Comment: What do those writers have that you don't? More experience, wider portfolio or?

Comment: Passive generating of leads often winds up with a passive income level. My image of such is that of a priest with a begging bowl sitting beside the roadway hoping to get some food from the passing people. I've heard from advertising people that it take 5-7 impressions to get through to someone. Passive doesn't do that unless other people are doing the active passing on of your "passive" work.